# nodejs: how to cut md5 digest into 4 long number by javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

my code is below, but sometimes it shows negative number, I think I have do it in wrong way. So I add max number to make it greater than zero, but binary operation is best.

```
var buff2hash = function(buff, part) {
    var hash = buff[part * 4 + 3] << 24 |
            buff[part * 4 + 2] << 16 |
            buff[part * 4 + 1] << 8 |
            buff[part * 4];
    //return hash // this number will be negative sometimes
    return hash < 0 ? hash + 4294967296 : hash;
};

var md5hashcode = exports.md5hashcode = function(key) {
    return buff2hash(new Buffer(crypto.createHash('md5').update(key).digest()), 0);
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most significant bit of the hash variable is the sign. To "hack convert" hash into an unsigned 32-bit integer you do this:

```
return hash>>>0;
```

(Forget about all the hoopla that you have in your "return" line, just do the above.)